# How to make node hierarchy with siblings and child pages

Tags: navigation

I want to make a node hierarchy menu which will display the child pages and siblings if child pages don't exist. I want to have the following structure

`parent
   child
   child
   child`
or

`parent
   sibling
   sibling`

Comment: @4k4 do you have any similar experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a entity reference field to find the parent node. On each child select the parent it belongs with.

In Views you can then create a "menu" by using views field views and passing the parent (content ID) argument into the child view.

In your parent view filter, make sure and filter by Parent is Empty to show only parents if there are no children.

On your child view, make sure Context has the entity reference to the parent.